# Js LocationPicker retrieving location data individually and apply to form

Tags: javascript

http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/#examples

I have a JS Googlemaps LocationPicker on my webpage, however I cannot make the autocomplete autofill the form.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" style="width:434px;">
    <div id="us2" class="mapclass"></div>          
</div>

<label id="citylable" for="city">Location</label>
<input id="cityinput" name="City" type="text" class="my-form-control" 
placeholder="Enter Your City"  required> </input>

<input id="citylat" name="citylat" type="text" class="my-form 
control" placeholder="Enter Your Latitude" style="display:none;"> 
</input>

<input id="citylong" name="citylong" type="text" class="my-form- 
control" placeholder="Enter Your Longitude" style="display:none;"></input>


  <label>Building*</label>
      <input id="address2" name="address2" class='my-form-control'/>

    <label>City*</label>
      <input id="locality" name="locality" class='my-form-control'required />

    <label>State/Province*</label>
      <input id="state" name="state" class='my-form-control' required />

    <label for="postal_code">Postal code*</label>
      <input id="postcode" name="postcode" class='my-form-control'required />

    <label>Country/Region*</label>
      <input id="country" name="country" class='my-form-control'required />


$('#us2').locationpicker({
    location: {
        latitude: 52.9470322,
        longitude: -1.1901637
    },
    radius: 50, addressFormat: 'locality',
    inputBinding: {
        locationNameInput: $('#cityinput'),
        latitudeInput: $('#citylat'),
        longitudeInput: $('#citylong'),
        
    },
    enableAutocomplete: true  
});
```

Also I am aware that there is Json, but I am very new to json and not sure how to receive the json data.

Currently the full address is returned using

```
locationNameInput: $('#cityinput')
```

which appends to the div cityinput.

However to apply this to the address form i am struggling with as LocationPicker does not provide this, only the google Places API does.

I have been watching Youtube videos and reading the Google API and the JS locationPicker Docs, however I am still very unsure how to approach this.

I tend to work by finding working code then amend it for my own purposes, however I cannot find the code I need.

Comment: From the code you've included it looks like the "locationpicker" is some kind of jQuery plugin?  Can you edit your question and add reference links/info about whatever you are using?

Comment: Ok i have added the link to the top of the post. Here it is again. 

http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/#examples

Comment: Thanks Marc_s - appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can get the formated address instead try this code

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-address" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Radius:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-radius" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="us3" style="width: 550px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="m-t-small">
        <label class="p-r-small col-sm-1 control-label">Lat.:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-lat" />
        </div>
        <label class="p-r-small col-sm-2 control-label">Long.:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-lon" />
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
        $('#us3').locationpicker({
            location: {
                latitude: 46.15242437752303,
                longitude: 2.7470703125
            },
            radius: 0,
            enableAutocomplete: false,
            enableAutocompleteBlur: false,
            autocompleteOptions: null,
            addressFormat: 'formated_address',
            enableReverseGeocode: true,
            draggable: true,
            onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {},
            onlocationnotfound: function(locationName) {},
            // must be undefined to use the default gMaps marker
            markerIcon: undefined,
            markerDraggable: true,
            markerVisible: true,
            inputBinding: {
                latitudeInput: $('#us3-lat'),
                longitudeInput: $('#us3-lon'),
                radiusInput: $('#us3-radius'),
                locationNameInput: $('#us3-address')
            },
            enableAutocomplete: true,
            onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
                // Uncomment line below to show alert on each Location Changed event
                //alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
            }
        });
    </script>
```